# Is there a way to make child packages write independently to catalog.operation_messages?

Tags: ssis

I've inherited many sets of SSIS packages which follow this structure:

In each group, one master package is executed by an SQL Server job.
The master package (barring some minimal logging operations) contains nothing but dozens of ExecutePackage tasks.  These call child packages, with ExecuteOutOfProcess False.

The ExecutePackage tasks are sometime arranged sequentially (linked with OnCompletion constraints), but sometimes in heavy parallelism: for example, one sequence container containing 40 ExecPackage tasks, with no constraints controlling their execution order.

This makes debugging problems very difficult.  SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages is my friend here.  But it seems that only the master package writes a row to catalog.executions, and all messages from all child packages end up mixed up, under that one operation_id which belongs to the master package.  Sometimes the component name in the message gives me a clue: but the previous developers often didn't change component names when cloning packages, so even that is misleading.

What would be great would be if each child package could write its own catalog.executions row, and then all its messages would be under that operation_id (execution_id in the catalog.executions table).  Is there any way of doing that?  Would ExecuteOutOfProcess=True do this, and does it have any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do *not* want to set ExecuteOutOfProcess=true.  This will spin up a new windows process called "DTS - surrogate service" for every prackage.  This will cost extra time in starting the child packages up and it will not affect logging in any way in the catalog.

What you do have in your existing process is that SSIS forces unique names within a container and the event messages have a property called "execution path," which will get you to the precise location of a task.  So this should help trace exceptions - the context link also will help with giving variable values.

Beyond that, it wouldn't hurt to re-architect it.  Consider:

- **Grouping related tasks** into sub-master packages
- **using executesql tasks and data flows instead of packages**, where the package doesn't give you anything but a container that a dataflow is executing in.  In other words, unravel the spaghetti.
- **Replacing generic names with ones that have meaning**.  Instead of "Execute Package 1," try "Load customer data into staging"
- **Adding restartability** into the process.  This could be done with a control table and it would give a high level picture of where the process fails.
- **Stage data** and make the staging tables forgiving. For example, if you have a field that needs to be converted to a date but sometimes it has invalid values, this is nice to put into a string column in a staging table, so you can find the value that's causing an eventual conversion error.

Comment: Very useful answer, thank you.  Redesign I agree is best.  Not possible right now (usual crap reasons - project overdue, "agile" etc).  Best workaround is this "execution path".  But where do you see this?  It's not in catalog.operation_messages.

Comment: You will find this in catalog.event_messages.  Also, if you use the standard reports in SSMS, they show it in there.  Lastly, the points above could be a lot of work depending on how sick the patient is.  I would recommend choosing to do one stage of refactoring at a time, so it's not a massive undertaking.  Rename stuff this month, regroup packages next month, replace child packages with dataflows the next and so on.

Comment: catalog.event_messages.package_path and execution_path are the solution for diagnosis.  Unfortunately child packages don't produce any execution reports of their own either!